# Composing PowerShell's Out-String within another function

Tags: powershell, pipeline, composition

I'd like to be able to write a version of PowerShell's `Out-String` that doesn't pad or truncate the resulting output.  I can achieve something like this using the following code:

```
Write-Host (Get-ChildItem env: | Out-String -Stream -Width 9999 | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Trim())`n" })
```

Resulting in the desired output:

```
 Name                           Value
 ----                           -----
 ALLUSERSPROFILE                C:\ProgramData
 APPDATA                        C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming
... etc ...
```

I'd like to capture this functionality into a new version of `Out-String`, but can't work out how to accomplish this.  This is as close as I've got:

```
filter Out-String2 {
  $_ | Out-String -Stream -Width 9999 | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Trim())`n" }
}

Write-Host (Get-ChildItem env: | Out-String2)
```

But this results in the undesirable effect of having each element of `Get-ChildItem` being rendered independently in the filter resulting in output like:

```
 Name                           Value
 ----                           -----
 ALLUSERSPROFILE                C:\ProgramData

 Name                           Value
 ----                           -----
 APPDATA                        C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming

...etc...
```

Is this kind of composition of pipeline elements possible in PowerShell, and if so - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work on a `filter`, but you can make use of the [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input) `$input` if you make a function out of this:

```
function Out-String2 {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        $Data
    )
    # if the data is sent through the pipeline, use $input to collect is as array
    if ($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) { $Data = @($input) }
    $Data | Out-String -Stream -Width 9999 | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Trim())`r`n" }
}
```

Call it using

```
Write-Host (Out-String2 (Get-ChildItem env:))
```

or

```
Write-Host (Get-ChildItem env: | Out-String2)
```